# Android SDK - updating xml doesn't update app

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am completely new to Andoid Studio, Java, and app development in general.

With that, in order to learn, I downloaded Android Studio version 2.3.  And, for my first project, I imported the accelerometer example from the sensors library.  I opened it, poked around, didn't change/save anything, and ran/installed the app on my phone (simply clicking the RUN button from the SDK), and it worked fine ... I see the metal balls rolling across my screen.

NEXT, I figured I would make a small change to the project and see what I have to do to rebuild/remake the app, since I see 'make project', 'make app', 'rebuild', 'build apk', and 'synchronize' ... still not sure what all those do exactly.

So, my simple change was in the app/res/layout/main.xml file, and all I changed was

from: 
`android:background="@drawable/wood"` 
to: 
`android:background="@drawable/ball"`

After this change, I went through every possible make, build, clean sequence I could think of, including the synchronize options within the different files. I've even disabled the instant run feature, uninstalled the app from my phone, restarted my phone, and restarted Android SDK.  I even found a checkbox to "skip installation if APK has not changed" in the RUN/DEBUG configuration window.

What am I missing?  Every time I RUN APP, it's as if no changes were made ... I get the same "wood" background from the original main.xml file.

Here is a link to the repo: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AccelerometerPlay/

Comment: Can you please post a link to the project you are working with?

Comment: Are you sure the app is using main.xml as the layout?

Comment: @JuanMartinez repo added to original post

Comment: @JimRhodes ... looks like `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` wasn't calling main.xml, instead it was using a simulation view.  Meh, glad it was easy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the code and if you take a look to the `AccelerometerPlayActivity` you can see that the background of the view that acts as the activity content (`SimulationView`) is being set on this piece of code (in the onCreate method):

```
// instantiate our simulation view and set it as the activity's content
mSimulationView = new SimulationView(this);
mSimulationView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wood);
setContentView(mSimulationView);
```

So, that's where you have to make your changes.